# Rails 4 with Papertrail gem not working on attribute change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

Just wondering why i cannot find any new records in `PaperTrail::Version.order('created_at DESC')` after adding [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem to my model using [workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) gem to track different states.

```
##in request.rb
##only need to add versions when workflow_state column changes
has_paper_trail only: [:workflow_state]
```

if i remove `only` option..everything works.Can someone help me to point what am i missing?

Moreover, Papertrail also mentions about using `attribute_name_was` only for attribute changes.Just wondering how can i use it if i cannot resolve above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The phrases ".. i cannot find any new records .." and ".. everything works .." are unclear to me. Please clarify the question.

Comment: i meant to say that after adding the papertrail block to a model, versioning should start for any change in the model attribute..but i cannot see any INSERT QUERY being fired....so its not working....hope this one is clear :).Even if i change it from rails console..nothing triggers.This is the issue link on github for papertrail -   https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/1004

Comment: Were you able to reproduce this issue using the [bug report template](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/doc/bug_report_template.rb)? It can be very helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: yeah will do that

Comment: seeing the same issue with the workflow gem, need to have it go later in the callback order, perhaps? did you ever figure this out? It looks like the github issue was closed with no investigation.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the issue on Github is closed,i had no other option but to wait for someone to get this issue fixed.

Comment: In my case, I was upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.2 and I needed to upgrade `paper_trail` to 9+ before it would actually record new versions. It was silently failing, which is big gotcha if your tests don't cover it.